# What is the meaning of this operator: *=

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, join

I have a very old Access application that uses SQL Pass-Through Queries.  This application has been nursed along through multiple server upgrades, and we recently moved up to SQL 2012.

I now get a syntax error.  The last two lines of the code are where the problem is.  I believe it is some kind of JOIN, but I've never seen this syntax.  Removing the "*" allows the query to run, but leaves out data.  Is there a easy replacement of this syntax or do I need to redesign these queries using the JOIN phrasing?

```sql
SELECT survey.hole,survey_date,pit,cu,rec,zn, mn,north,east,elevation,
       rtrim(min_type) min_type,rtrim(rock_type) rock_type,
       rtrim(alt_type) alt_type, rtrim(min_style) min_style
FROM survey,assay,geology 
WHERE  mined_out IS NULL
AND pit = (SELECT fmpit FROM tyrctl WHERE source = 'export by date')
AND  (survey_date >= (SELECT fmdate FROM tyrctl WHERE source = 'export by date') 
AND survey_date <= (SELECT todate FROM tyrctl WHERE source = 'export by date')) 
AND survey.hole *= assay.hole
AND survey.hole *= geology.hole
```

Comment: That is the "old-style" JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is using the pre-ANSI (and possibly original) JOIN syntax. Back in "the day", joining tables was done by specifying all of the tables, separated by commas, in the `FROM` clause, and then specifying the join condition(s) in the `WHERE` clause. Equating the current ANSI style with the old style gives you the following chart of options:

- [INNER] JOIN: `TableA.Field = TableB.Field`
- LEFT [OUTER] JOIN: `TableA.Field *= TableB.Field`
- RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN: `TableA.Field =* TableB.Field`
- <del>FULL [OUTER] JOIN: `TableA.Field *=* TableB.Field`</del>
- CROSS JOIN: `{nothing specified to relate the two tables}`

The pre-ANSI syntax is / was supported (sometimes with slight variation) by the [various RDBMSes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Alternative_syntaxes). However, it has been deprecated for a while in Microsoft SQL Server, and was officially removed in SQL Server 2012 (as you are now seeing). This was noted in the [Discontinued Database Engine Functionality in SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262(v=sql.110).aspx) MSDN page (2nd to last row in the grid).

In your query, you have 3 tables:

```sql
FROM survey,assay,geology
```

and two LEFT JOIN conditions:

```sql
AND survey.hole *= assay.hole
AND survey.hole *= geology.hole
```

But yes, you can rewrite it as follows:

```sql
SELECT sy.hole, survey_date, pit, cu, rec, zn, mn, north, east, elevation,
       rtrim(min_type) AS [min_type], rtrim(rock_type) AS [rock_type],
       rtrim(alt_type) AS [alt_type], rtrim(min_style) AS [min_style]
FROM survey sy
LEFT JOIN assay ay
       ON ay.hole = sy.hole
LEFT JOIN geology gy
       ON gy.hole = sy.hole
WHERE  mined_out IS NULL
AND pit = (SELECT fmpit FROM tyrctl WHERE source = 'export by date')
AND (
      survey_date >= (SELECT fmdate FROM tyrctl WHERE source = 'export by date')
  AND survey_date <= (SELECT todate FROM tyrctl WHERE source = 'export by date')
    )
```

Technically, you don't need the parenthesis around the two `survey_date` conditions in the `WHERE` clause as they are all `AND` conditions, but if you prefer it for readability then it is fine.

---

As @ypercube pointed out in a comment on this answer, the query can be further simplified to since the 3 subqueries in the `WHERE` clause all reference the same row of the same table. So that could look at follows:

```sql
SELECT sy.hole, survey_date, pit, cu, rec, zn, mn, north, east, elevation,
       rtrim(min_type) AS [min_type], rtrim(rock_type) AS [rock_type],
       rtrim(alt_type) AS [alt_type], rtrim(min_style) AS [min_style]
FROM survey sy
INNER JOIN tyrctl tl
        ON sy.survey_date >= tl.fmdate
       AND sy.survey_date <= tl.todate
       AND sy.pit = tl.fmpit
       AND tl.source = 'export by date'
LEFT JOIN assay ay
       ON ay.hole = sy.hole
LEFT JOIN geology gy
       ON gy.hole = sy.hole
WHERE  mined_out IS NULL;
```

Comment: Was there really an `*=*` operator? I thought only `*=` and `=*` were there.

Comment: It gives me an `Incorrect syntax near '*'` error when I try a query with `*=*` in SQL Server 2008 R2. (Works fine with the other two.) I tried it in a database with a matching compatibility level (80), of course.

Comment: The 3 subqueries have identical conditions so they could be replaced by a single correlated one: `AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tyrctl WHERE source = 'export by date' AND x.pit = fmpit AND y.survey_date >= fmdate AND y.survey_date <= todate)` - where `x` and `y` are the correct aliases (`sy`, `ay` or `gy`)

Comment: @ypercube regarding the `*=*` syntax, I could be misremembering. I originally learned this stuff on DB2/MVS back in mid '96. Between that and there being vendor-specific variations, maybe it was never in SQL Server. Maybe it was never anywhere and I dreamt it up ;-). I will cross it off for now. And good call on reducing the `AND` conditions. That could just as well be a simple INNER JOIN since it only matches one row in `tyrctl`. Also, I assume those fields are in the main `survey` table (`sy`) else the rows coming back wouldn't be reduced.